# How to fetch single row using withGraphJoined?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js, objection.js

There are two tables users and activities.

I am able to join these using `withGraphJoined`. The response json is like this,

```
[
  {
    user: 'first',
    activity: [{ type: 'act1' }, { type: 'act2' }],
  },

  {
    user: 'second',
    activity: [{ type: 'act3' }, { type: 'act2' }],
  },
];
```

Now i want to fetch only the first activity and make current array into first activity object. `{user:"second", activity:{type:"act3}}`

I tried this but still i get all the activity in array.

```
User.query()
  .withGraphJoined('activity')
  .modifyGraph('activity', (builder) => builder.first());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how you define the relationship
if you want it to return a single object then the relation should use `Model.HasOneRelation` or `Model.BelongsToOneRelation`

however if you just want to return a single activity from many you can limit the results

```
.modifyGraph('activity', (builder) => builder.orderBy('created_at', 'desc').limit(1));
```

but it will still return an array with one item that you can access by `activity[0]`
the only way i can think of is if you manually map this first item in your `then` like

```
.then(user => {
    user.activity = user.activity[0] ? user.activity[0] : {}
    res.json(user)
})
```

to be on the safe side, you can check if the item exists first to avoid null error

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by converting to Model.HasOneRelation. But, I also tried the other approach .modifyGraph('activity', (builder) => builder.orderBy('created_at', 'desc').limit(1)); . It gives the correct one item in array but only for the last item activity array.  All the other activity arrays were empty. When i did "asc" It then gave only for the top item correct activity others were empty? Is this what supposed to happen?

Comment: yes, that's the `.limit(1)` returning only a single item, the order is just to get the `latest` value, you can query for the single item however you want  for example if you have many addresses and only want the one with `.where('active',true)`

Comment: ah i see what you mean by "All the other activity arrays were empty" that's not how i thought this would work, you can still use the manual mapping trick without the `.limit(1)`  if you need to define HasMany or ManyToMany